# Using grep to filter process

Tags: linux

```
root      1626     1  0 04:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
USERNAME    5133  5038  0 14:12 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./find_proc.sh sshd
USERNAME  5137  5133  0 14:12 pts/0    00:00:00 grep sshd
```

How can i use grep to filter out the bottom to processes?

```
ps -ef | grep "$1"
```

is what gets me that output. I know you need to use grep -v to filter it out, however i am not sure of the order to do it in. It takes an Argument which is $1. So my input in the terminal is ./script_file sshd to get the output above. Any suggestions?

```
ps -ef | grep "$1" | grep -v grep
```

gives me no output.

Comment: why don't use cut or awk and such commands istead of grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pgrep`. It is available on most of the modern Linux and Unix systems (on OSX available via `home brew`):

```
pgrep -fl "$1"
```

Comment: `pgrep` is the way to go. It doesn't cause issues with having to filter out `grep` from your _grepped_ output.

Comment: `pgrep` and `pkill` were included in OS X in Mavericks.

Comment: As in ps -ef | pgrep -fl "$1" ?

Comment: Thanks @DavidW.: I am still on older `OSX 10.6.8`

Comment: @user2860658: No don't use `ps -ef |`. Just use `pgrep -fl "$1"`

Comment: It doesn't seem to give me the output i want.                      1626 /usr/sbin/sshd
                                                                  5316 /bin/bash ./find_proc.sh sshd

Comment: what output do you want OR what is missing?

Comment: I just need "root      1626     1  0 04:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd" to show up when i run ./script_file sshd

Comment: This is what i have                                                                           #!/bin/bash

filename=$1

ps -ef | head -1

ps -ef | grep "$1"

Comment: You can use `pgrep -fl -G "$1"` for more output columns

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that you'e running something like `ps aux | grep sshd`, and `grep` ends up finding itself in the process list? There's a simple trick to work around that, namely to enclose one character in brackets:

```
ps aux | grep ssh[d]
```

The `[d]` is interpreted by `grep` in the same way as `d`, but it's still part of the command line so it doesn't include the string `sshd`.

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks @DavidW.: I am still on older OSX 10.6.8

Snow Leopard has a similar command to `pgrep` and `pill` called [killall](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/killall.1.html). In many ways, `killall` is superior to `pgrep` and `pkill`, but it is also a bit more complex to use.

One of the parameters is the `-s` parameter which will merely *show* what it will do.

The main problem with `killall` is that it can kill if you're not careful:

```
$ killall -s $command
kill -TERM 2193
kill -TERM 32832
```